# How I use a local container in a swarm cluster

Tags: docker, cluster-computing

A colleague find out Docker and want to use it for our project. I start to use Docker for test. After reading an article about Docker swarm I want to test it.

I have installed 3 VM (ubuntu server 14.04) with docker and swarm. I followed some How To ( http://blog.remmelt.com/2014/12/07/docker-swarm-setup/ and http://devopscube.com/docker-tutorial-getting-started-with-docker-swarm/). My cluster work. I can launch for exemple a basic apache container (the image was pull in the Docker hub) but I want to use my own image (an apache server with my web site).

I tested to load an image (after save it in a .tar) but this option isn't supported by the clustering mode, same thing with the import option.

So my question is : Can I use my own image without to push it in the Docker hub and how I do this ?

Comment: It's kind of early to be testing swarm.

Answer (score 0):

If your own image is based on a Dockerfile that you build you can execute the build command on your project while targeting the swarm.

However if the image wasn't built, but created manually you need to have a registry in between that you can push to, either docker hub or some other registry solution like https://github.com/docker/docker-registry

Comment: I have tested the build command  but it's not supported by swarm. swarm error when I use docker build --> FATA[0000] Error: Not supported in clustering mode.

Comment: Okay, have not had the chance to hack at swarm yet. But that would seem to indicate that you cannot send a build context to the swarm.